# Magento module admin 404 after move to a new server

Tags: magento, module, http-status-code-404, admin

I've been devolving several Magento modules on a Mac's local Apache server. Lately, I've moved the modules to a new Magento install on a new server. My problem is that all but one is 404-ing when I'm trying to load their admin pages. I can't find any reason why this one module works and the others don't even try to load pages. Most if the code is very similar from one to the next. Also, the 404 pages are not helpful and there are no exception or log entries to help me. These all work on the old server, and although some of the code has bad/old links that need to be fixed, and those generate errors I see no reason they aren't trying to load pages and generating errors.

I think the configs work, because I get the admin menu. Since the layouts have nothing concerning the front part of URL's, I see no reason for the problem to be them, either. I could post code, but I have no idea what to post that could be causing this.

I would greatly appreciate any insight that could be causing this.

Comment: your online server are Linux??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i devolve modules on windows and send to Linux, sometimes forget and make some thing on capital letter and others on lowcase, windows isn't case sensitive on this case, but linux is. maybe is the same on Macs / Linux

Comment: It is exactly the same with a Mac. I have a bunch of things that the Mac lets slide, that has been causing me grief. EX: indexController=> IndexController. I thought that there were going to be errors with wrong-caps, but evidently not if its the index controller. Also, I had to 777 the log files before they would work.